# Passing a null value to a ManyToOne relationship colum throws an error in JPA

Tags: jpa, db2, websphere-liberty

I have the following entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class ClassA {
 @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_idkey", nullable = true)
    protected Subject subject;
}
```

When I try to persist this entity to database with subject being set as NULL,I get the following error.

Unrecognized JDBC type: 2001. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null

This happens only if this entity is persisted using the code which runs in an application server.

Junit test case written to test the same function works fine.

Here is the code which updates the student details to the database

ClassA student = new ClassA();
student.setSubject(null);

```
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(student);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Any idea on how this problem could be resolved?

Comment: show us the code that persists the entity

Comment: and the SQL used to INSERT

Comment: Please provide the exception stack as well; down to the line it fails in your application code

Comment: the above post has been updated with the code to save the entity